# How to get user defined system colors on Linux?

Tags: java, linux, awt, gnome, kde-plasma

How do I get correct colors associated with my KDE or Gnome profile on Linux?

java.awt.SystemColor seems to give me root (?) account colors, at least colors definitions doesn't match my settings (whereas on Windows everything is fine).

Are there any APIs that let me access current user's Window Manager color settings from Java?

Comment: Check [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20110627190622/http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2009/12/java_tip_how_use_systemcolors_access_os_user_interface_theme_colors) page and especially [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20110627190258/http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2010/06/java_tip_systemcolors_linux_kde_user_interface_themes#DealingwithKDESystemColorproblems) page!